# Improving Neural network regression model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, regression, data-fitting

I have the following toy data (which closely mimicks my original larger data used for the project):

```
x = np.array([ 0.        ,  0.1010101 ,  0.2020202 ,  0.3030303 ,  0.4040404 ,
        0.50505051,  0.60606061,  0.70707071,  0.80808081,  0.90909091,
        1.01010101,  1.11111111,  1.21212121,  1.31313131,  1.41414141,
        1.51515152,  1.61616162,  1.71717172,  1.81818182,  1.91919192,
        2.02020202,  2.12121212,  2.22222222,  2.32323232,  2.42424242,
        2.52525253,  2.62626263,  2.72727273,  2.82828283,  2.92929293,
        3.03030303,  3.13131313,  3.23232323,  3.33333333,  3.43434343,
        3.53535354,  3.63636364,  3.73737374,  3.83838384,  3.93939394,
        4.04040404,  4.14141414,  4.24242424,  4.34343434,  4.44444444,
        4.54545455,  4.64646465,  4.74747475,  4.84848485,  4.94949495,
        5.05050505,  5.15151515,  5.25252525,  5.35353535,  5.45454545,
        5.55555556,  5.65656566,  5.75757576,  5.85858586,  5.95959596,
        6.06060606,  6.16161616,  6.26262626,  6.36363636,  6.46464646,
        6.56565657,  6.66666667,  6.76767677,  6.86868687,  6.96969697,
        7.07070707,  7.17171717,  7.27272727,  7.37373737,  7.47474747,
        7.57575758,  7.67676768,  7.77777778,  7.87878788,  7.97979798,
        8.08080808,  8.18181818,  8.28282828,  8.38383838,  8.48484848,
        8.58585859,  8.68686869,  8.78787879,  8.88888889,  8.98989899,
        9.09090909,  9.19191919,  9.29292929,  9.39393939,  9.49494949,
        9.5959596 ,  9.6969697 ,  9.7979798 ,  9.8989899 , 10.        ])
y = np.array([-0.80373298,  0.76935298, -0.14159923,  1.29519353,  0.3094064 ,
        0.66238427,  0.42343774,  0.77283061,  1.47505766,  0.45931619,
        1.41141125,  1.62579566,  1.28840108,  1.34285815,  0.9329334 ,
        1.329214  ,  1.5139391 ,  1.21117778,  0.54639438,  0.51462165,
        2.77181805,  1.13110837,  1.86706418,  1.95244603,  1.40661855,
        1.30664676,  1.79014375,  1.39412399,  1.17882416,  1.06187797,
        1.89504248,  1.50652787,  1.64920352,  2.69228877,  2.24660016,
        1.8767469 ,  2.22418453,  1.63944449,  1.81288111,  1.59961924,
        1.7354012 ,  1.65975252,  2.04371439,  2.51920563,  2.3971049 ,
        1.74297775,  2.22420045,  1.29922847,  1.78963033,  2.76862922,
        2.59913081,  2.5868994 ,  0.95132831,  2.33654116,  2.14236444,
        2.56886641,  2.41801508,  2.03847576,  1.76058536,  1.47914731,
        3.22155981,  2.77761667,  2.43482125,  2.87060182,  2.71857598,
        2.39742888,  2.55224796,  2.03309053,  2.85056195,  3.01513978,
        3.1316874 ,  2.14246426,  1.88901478,  2.30135553,  2.90525156,
        3.08009528,  2.0941706 ,  3.05404934,  3.59780609,  2.32416305,
        3.04954219,  1.36782575,  3.16888341,  2.26659839,  2.14637558,
        3.26594114,  3.47156645,  3.27828348,  3.48980836,  2.66734284,
        2.69708374,  2.90246668,  2.48449401,  3.13271428,  3.08989781,
        3.05270477,  3.96243953,  3.28104845,  2.46014121,  3.95762993])
```

my goal is to do a regression/fit to the data and obtain a good model which can reciprocate this data pattern.For this I used initially, simple polynomial regression, then neural network, with a single layer, then with 2 layers, however in all cases, I am unhappy at how it fails to grasp the pattern at the low x values where the data dips suddenly (along Y axis).

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Reshape x to be a 2D array of size (N, 1)
x = x_data
y = y_data
x = x.reshape(-1, 1)

# Define the model
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(10, input_dim=1, activation='relu'),  # input layer and hidden layer with 10 neurons
    keras.layers.Dense(1)                                    # output layer with 1 neuron
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Train the model
model.fit(x, y, epochs=500, verbose=0)

# Make predictions with the model
y_pred = model.predict(x)

# Plot the original data and the model's predictions
plt.scatter(x, y, label='Original data')
plt.plot(x, y_pred, color='red', label='Fitted line')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: NN regression]

Second try :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras

x = x_data
y = y_data

# Preprocess data
x = x.reshape(-1,1)  # Needs to be reshaped for Keras
y = y.reshape(-1,1)

# Building the model
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=x.shape[1:]),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Train the model
history = model.fit(x, y, epochs=50, verbose=0)

# Make predictions with the model
y_pred = model.predict(x)

# Plotting the loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
plt.scatter(x, y, label='Original data')
plt.plot(x, y_pred, color='red', label='Fitted line')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: 2nd NN model]

As we see, in both cases it fails to capture the low x-value trend. I would like to ask if there are ways to improve this or other algorithms.

Comment: Any sort of statistical analysis won't fit your outliers (dips). By definition. You need completely different approach. Like reinforcement learning.

Comment: can you point me to some suitable material ? or give a toy example on which I can build ?